# First time developing in XAML, cannot make my chat work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, chat

First time I program an app in XAML, I learned from different sources and I am trying to make an app. Right now I am working on making a good looking chat but ran into an error that I cannot solve at all.

The part that bugs start in the MainWindow:

```
<chat:ChatViewModel/>
```

This calls the user control `CharViewModel` that creates the chat. Here is the XAML part of this user control:

```xaml
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:IncomingMessage}">
        <Grid >
            <Border Background="Orange" CornerRadius="15 15 0 15" Margin="10 12">
                <TextBlock Margin="15" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="CadetBlue" Text="{Binding MessageContent}"/>
            </Border>
            <TextBlock Text="Thu 5:45PM" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="10" Margin="10 0"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:OutgoingMessage}">
        <Grid >
            <Border Background="Gray" CornerRadius="15 15 0 15" Margin="10 12">
                <TextBlock Margin="15" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="CadetBlue" Text="{Binding MessageContent}"/>
            </Border>
            <TextBlock Text="Thu 5:45PM" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="10" Margin="10 0"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:MessageList/>
</UserControl.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}"/>
</Grid>
```

Here is the C# code:

```cs
public partial class ChatViewModel : UserControl
{
    public ChatViewModel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

This is how my MessageList looks like :

```java
class MessageList : ViewModelBase
{
    public MessageList()
    {
        Messages = new ObservableCollection<Message>();
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}
```

To finish, this is the code in the MainWindow.cs that creates the list of message from a text file. Each message is of the form "David/Hi how are u?" in the text file:

```cs
var ListMessage = new MessageList();
using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader("../Utilisateur/Chat.txt"))
{
    string text;
    while ((text = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] list = text.Split('/');
        if (list[0] == "David")
        {
            ListMessage.Messages.Add(new OutgoingMessage { MessageContent = list[1] });
        }
        else
        {
            ListMessage.Messages.Add(new IncomingMessage { MessageContent = list[1] });
        }
                    
    }
}
```

With the message class looking like this:

```java
public class Message : ViewModelBase
{
    ///Sender Name
    public string SenderName { get; set; }

    ///Text of the message
    private string _messageContent;
    public string MessageContent
    {
        get
        {
            return _messageContent;
        }
        set
        {
            _messageContent = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MessageContent");
        }
    }

    ///True if message has been read
    public bool MessageRead;
    
    ///Time the message was sent
    public DateTimeOffset MessageSentTime { get; set; }
}
```

And the ViewModelBase that I copied from the internet because I don't fully understand how it works

```java
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}
```

Here I have a text file with each line representing a message of the form "NameOfTheTender/Message".

Then I want to display the messages as small bubble, orange and on the left side of the window if I received the message, gray and on the right side if I sent it. For the moment nothing shows on the window.
[How the window looks like right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rj6TG.png)

Comment: `<local:MessageList/>` in the UserControl's DataContext and `new MessageList()` in the Window's code behind create two different MessageList instances. Adding items to one of  them has no effect on the other. Your UserControl should not set its own DataContext. It should instead inherit the DataContext value from the MainWindow.

Comment: How could i change my code to do what you said ? Because I had feeling that this was the problem. And thanks for the advice, I will change the name of my futur views !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<local:MessageList/>` in the UserControl's DataContext and `new MessageList()` in the Window's code behind create two different MessageList instances. Adding items to one of them has no effect on the other.

Your UserControl should not set its own DataContext. Remove this DataContent assignment from the UserControl's XAML:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:MessageList/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

In order to make the UserControl bind to the MessageList instance created in the MainWindow, just assign that to the Window's DataContext:

```
var ListMessage = new MessageList();
DataContext = ListMessages;
```

The value of the DataContext property will now be inherited by the UserControl.

Comment: Just did what you said and now my bubbles works thanks a lot, but the contact list on the left (see the image) doesn't show anything, anyway to setup different datacontext ?

Comment: No idea what "*the contact list on the left*" is supposed to be. There is nothing about it in your question. Probably ask a new question and show the relevant details.

Comment: I was refering to the image that I linked at the end of my initial message, I was using the datacontext for my contact but now that I changed it, it is not working anymore. I will try to solve it by myself and if I cannot I will make a new question. Thanks for all